# How to build rpm from war

Tags: java, tomcat7, war, rpm, rpmbuild

I have been reading about building rpm from war files & use them for installation. As part of it I downloaded [sample war](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/sample/sample.war)  and trying to create rpm. My tomcat version is 7.0. I ran rpmdev-setuptree which creates the directory hierarchy needed for rpm build. All I intend to do by installing the rpm is :  stop tomcat, delete the sample.war & sample folder from webapps, copy new war to webapps & start tomcat. Can I accomplish it? or rather I would like to know, is this the correct way of using rpm build from the war?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: It would be easier to e.g. use maven rpm plugin to build the war.

Comment: @krzyk being not a java developer, I don't understand maven. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using maven you can use the [RPM maven plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/)